# Spaces in Inline scripting in Asp.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Today when I was working on some javascript in an Asp.NET page, I did something like this:

```
<script type="type/javascript">
    var elementID = document.getElementById("<%=txtMyServerControl.ClientID %>")
</script>
```

And compiler threw an error and once I added a space between `=` and `txtMyServerControl` and it stopped complaining about it and worked. BUT however without space it is working perfectly on my co-worker's computer?

Am I missing something?

**Note:** This is the error, there wasn't any other problem and yes, I compiled several times before realizing this was the error.

Comment: Maybe the <script></script> confuse it, maybe a small bug/issue on compiler, don't bother and move on.

Comment: @Aristos You're right but I just wanted why it might have happened so I wouldn't miss this error ever again, I know it is kind of detail.

Comment: If you used 'Response.Write(txtMyServerControl)' instead of the <%= %> does it make any difference?

Comment: What was the exact error the compiler gave?

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but does it work if you change "type/javascript" to "text/javascript"?

Comment: @greg84: I haven't seen that before. Good catch. I am not really sure which was the cause since we already uploaded this project to the server and it is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elementID = document.getElementById("<%=txtMyServerControl.ClientID %>")
</script>
```